# C - SIGSEGV Whilst trying to append to GTKTextBuffer

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, append, gtk

I'm trying to write a function to append a given text string to the end of my GTKTextBuffer, however am having issues with what I assume to be memory allocation issues?

So, here is the function I have written to do the append:

```
void append_to_log(GtkTextBuffer *buffer, char* strToSave) {

    GtkTextIter *iter;

    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, iter);

    gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, iter, strToSave, strlen(strToSave));

}
```

When I try to start my program, and add a "Logging started... \n" message using the function...

```
append_to_log(loggingBuffer, "Logging started... \n");
```

...I get this error:

```
/home/csc/CLionProjects/SDS-CW/GUIs/Server/cmake-build-debug/SDS-CW
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

However, when I try manually adding the first line, it works fine:

```
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(loggingBuffer, "Logging started... \n", 20);
```

So I tried setting an inital line manually, then appending a new line afterwards...

```
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(loggingBuffer, "Logging started... \n", 20);
append_to_log(loggingBuffer, "Logging continued... \n");
```

... I get a Segmentation Fault.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong, and how I may be able to fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GtkTextIter iter;
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &iter);
```

You need to give pointer to existing `GtkTextIter` instance, and not pointer to nowhere, as in your code.

Comment: Ah yes, that sorted it! Stupid mistake on my part aha. Thank you! I will accept answer as soon as it lets me.